# junit Test for the exception method

Tags: java

How to junit test this exception method. What to provide in the `assertEquals` method.

```
public void sys(){
  try
    {
        String s = null;
        System.out.println(s.length());
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: public void sysTest(){
  ExceptionHandling e= new ExceptionHandling();
  assertEquals("de", "Hello");

Comment: BTW, you have an extra closing bracket in your code.

Comment: What is sys method supposed to do?

Comment: it just checks length of the string.. if it is null it throws the exception @pubudu

Answer (score 2):

You can write a junit test which expects an Exception

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void sys() {
    String s = null;
    System.out.println(s.length());
}
```